# Função para agilizar select

Tags: php

Olá

Eu estou desenvolvendo umas funções para agilizar inserir select e evitar lotar de codigo PHP nas paginas, eu crie uma função chamada **select_inicio** e outra função chamada **select_termino** e quando chamo essas duas funções, entre elas eu insiro onde sera exibido os resultados do select, mas não esta funcionando, oque pode estar errado ?

```
include 'include/connection.php';

function select_inicio()
{
    $query = "SELECT id, imagem, produto FROM produtos ORDER BY id ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
}

function select_termino()
{
    }
}

?>
</head>
<body>
<?php select_inicio(); ?>
<?php echo $row[0]; ?>
<?php select_termino(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você não pode começar o `while` numa função e terminar na outra!

Comment: Sugestões: identar o código, ler e entender o erro que provavelmente está aparecendo em algum lugar (ou na tela ou no log) e mais: conferir a colorização de código e fechamento de parênteses e chaves. 
(Por que a função "select_termino" fecha a chaves duas vezes?) ;)

Comment: Qual sugestão vocês me dão, para eu poder apenas chamar a função em uma determinada pagina e exibir o resultadodo while dentro de um <span>, sem precisar ficar inserindo a query e o while na pagina de exibição, sempre que eu precisar listar os resultado ?

Comment: inserir a query e o while no local que precisa listar os resultados é o correto, qualquer coisa que tentar fazer para mudar isso será uma gambiarra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque tudo numa função só:

```
include 'include/connection.php';

function select($query)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $retorno[] = $row;
    }
}
?>

<body>
<?php 
    $res = select("SELECT id, imagem, produto FROM produtos ORDER BY id ASC");
    var_dump($res);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Depois você poder usar um `foreach ($res AS $linha) {...}` para tratar cada linha do retorno da sua consulta ou acessar uma linha especifica com `$res[0]['campo']`.
Bom, é só o princípio a ser usado, vc precisa desenvolver melhor o código, lembre-se de tratar também as possibilidades de erros com `mysqli->error`

Answer (score 0):

Você não está fechando a primeira função e acabou inserindo uma função dentro de outra função e isso da erro de sintaxe. O correto seria:

```
include 'include/connection.php';

function select_inicio()
{
    $query = "SELECT id, imagem, produto FROM produtos ORDER BY id ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    }

}

function select_termino()
{

}

?>
</head>
<body>
<?php select_inicio(); ?>
<?php echo $row[0]; ?>
<?php select_termino(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```